# Adding an event in google calendar from my android application

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Hello I am a beginner in android. 
I want to add an event in google calendar from my android application.
Please help me with complete source code. I have looked, but haven't found a solution with complete source code.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can use ContentValues like local db,

```
String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.TITLE, "YOUR_TITLE");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.DTSTART, TIMES IN MILLISECOND);


        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.DESCRIPTION,YOUR_TEXT);

        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.DTEND,  TIMES IN MILLISECOND);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.HAS_ALARM, true);


        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

 Uri uriEvents = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
 eventID = Long.parseLong(uriEvents.getLastPathSegment());
```